# CakePHP UpdateAll Only Updating Last Entered Data

Tags: cakephp

I have built an invoice system in my new CakePHP site and I am currently trying to build a function that will let me save the re-edited information back into the same records.

Below is the section of code I am working on,

```
    $InvoiceDataVar = $this->data['Invoicedata'];

    foreach ($InvoiceDataVar as $DataKey => $DataValue) {

        $UpdateWork = $InvoiceDataVar[$DataKey]['workdes'];
        debug($UpdateWork);
        $this->Invoicedata->updateAll(
                                      array('Invoicedata.workdes' => "'$UpdateWork'"),
                                      array('Invoicedata.invoicejoblists_id' => $InvoiceID)
                                      );
    }
```

This is work $this->data holds,

```
  'Invoicedata' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 1',
        'price' => '500.00'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 2',
        'price' => '501.00'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 3',
        'price' => '503.00'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 4',
        'price' => '504.00'
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 5',
        'price' => '505.00'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'workdes' => 'test new update 6',
        'price' => '999.99'
    )
)
```

These are of course just test data, but unless I am not understanding the UpdateAll function documentation which I have gone over many times, all this will do is update all the six fields with the last test input. Right now all the fields for the workdes contain, 'test new update 6'.

I should also say that there might not be all ways be six fields, there will always be at lest one, with a max (at this time) of 6 inputs to update.

I was thinking about loading the 'ID of the invoicedata table, which is an auto count number, where as the joblist_id is the same id in all the the fields being updated? This is my current line of thinking....

Any Help is most welcome.

Glenn.

Comment: Looks like you have updateAll and save confused - what you're doing right now is updated multiple rows in a loop, with a scope such that you'll update the same rows each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are working with CakePHP 1.3

To udpate many records at once there is a shortcut way shown in documentation

First you need to include ids of Invoicedata model in the post data

```
'Invoicedata' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => 23, // include id of the record
        'workdes' => 'test new update 1',
        'price' => '500.00'
    ),
    // other records
)

// then call save all function
$this->Invoicedata->saveAll($this->data['Invoicedata']);
```

Comment: Nope, I am working with CakePHP 2.3.something... When I used the SaveAll function, which I did at 1st, all that would happen would be that it would save a whole new set of data and not update the current values.

Comment: You need to include 'id' to update records otherwise it will insert new

Comment: ummm, that might have been where I was going wrong, but not sure how to get the id data, I am guesting here but I would have to load it into the form that submits the data. I work on it, many thanks. Just as a side note, SaveAll is or can use used then to do almost all tasks? So why is there an update function?

Comment: updateAll function can work with direct conditions, eg. if you want to update certain fields matching some conditions, you don't need to pass any data, it will accept SQL conditions

Comment: yes, you have to include ids in hidden fields while rendering form for editing, cake will also autopopulate hidden fields of id

Answer (score 0):

Please, check: [updateAll documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-Model.html#_updateAll) you can see, that first parameter is `$fields`, which fields you wanto to update and their appropriate values, and second parameter is  `$conditions` some restrictions which define scope of rows which will be changed. You have empty `$conditions`, so, all rows will be updated. Last values ( here you need to check source code of DataSource update method), but think that it produce some think like

```
UPDATE invoicedatas SET workdes = value1, price = value2,  workdes = value3, price = value4 and etc
```

so last values will be used.

Your data arrays should contain `id` attribute, to update right records and for this you should use `save` or `saveAll` methods of Invoicedata model.